# Decoding multiply qr codes from JPEG / PNG

Tags: javascript, image-processing, qr-code

my question is a conceptual one. i'm working on a project that includes the **Idea** of taking pictures from events (lets suppose they were taken with a high resolution camera), the pictures will include people wearing QR code stickers, preferably small ones (i know the size matters). 
after searching the web I've found a few decoders such as [jsqrcode library](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/271/how-to-decode-a-qr-code-from-an-image-with-javascript), so if i have a few QR codes in the picture will a decoder be able to discover them and give me an output of the info? or do i need to make some pre-processes in order to decode every QR code? (i'm a beginner in terms of JS coding etc.)
i need to understand if its even feasible.
every answer will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Count about three pixels per cell in the captured images, otherwise the codes won't be readable. And only those reasonably facing the camera and not too much distorted will work.

Comment: And does the number of mega pixels of the camera will matter in this case? If I have more pixels this means It will be easier to read the barcode?

Comment: @TalHanegbi: too many is also bad: it will uselessly increase the processing time.